# List containing sub-classes in C++ (vs. generics in Java)

Tags: c++, generics, c++20

Coming from the Java world, I'm trying to accomplish something similar to

```java
import java.util.List;

class BaseClass {
    protected List<? extends BaseClass> members;
}

class ClassA extends BaseClass {
    public ClassA(List<ClassA> args) {   // I want to have only ClassA objects here
        this.members = args;
    }
}
```

Now in C++, the following doesn't compile because of the mismatch

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class BaseClass {
protected:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>> children;
};

class ClassA : public BaseClass {
    explicit ClassA(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ClassA>>& args) {
        this->children = args;  // error here
    }
};
```

The compilation error is

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<BaseClass>’ and ‘const std::vector<ClassA>’)
   11 |         this->children = args;
      |                          ^~~~
```

What would be the most idiomatic/cleanest solution? I'm using C++20.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>` and `std::shared_ptr<ClassA>` as well as `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>>` and `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ClassA>>` are _unrelated_ classes even if `class ClassA: public BaseClass`. You could try to initialize `children` with `children(args.begin(), args.end())`. The constructor / assignment of `std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>` should accept `std::shared_ptr<ClassA>` (similar like `ClassA*` can initialize / be assigned to `BaseClass*`).

Comment: while a `ClassA` is-a `BaseClass`, `vector<ClassA>` and `vector<BaseClass>` are not related whether references are involved or not. It's going to have to be `vector` of `BaseClass` references all the way down, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat `std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>` and `std::shared_ptr<ClassA>` *are* related, there's an implicit conversion from the latter to the former.

Comment: If it weren't closed already, would vote to close for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76004849/cast-vectorint-to-vectorunsigned-int/76005027#76005027

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way in C++ to cast a vector of Ts into a vector of Us, even if U inherits from T. As such you need to insert `args` one by one; however, the implementation of `shared_ptr` makes it such that you do not need to explicitly cast. (If you ever do need to explicitly cast you can use `std::static_pointer_cast`)

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class BaseClass {
protected:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>> children;
};

class ClassA : public BaseClass {
public:
    explicit ClassA(const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ClassA>>& args = {}) {
        children.reserve(args.size());
        for (auto arg : args) {
            children.push_back(arg);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Why the `std::static_pointer_cast<BaseClass>(arg)`?

Comment: oh right it's not needed? ... ill change the answer. (i didn't actually run this code)

Comment: `children.assign(args.begin(), args.end())` works

Comment: Actually there is a casting mechnism. But it is really modest and many just skip it.